# result in Sequential feature selection

Tags: matlab

i want get best features by Sequential feature selection in matlab 2014a.
this is my code but only show 1 column from 30 column !(dataset : wbcd)

```
Y = cell2mat(Y);
P=cvpartition(Y,'holdout',0.20);
rbfsigma=1.41;

train_x=X(P.training,:);
train_y=Y(P.training);
test_x=X(P.test,:);
test_y=Y(P.test);

svmStruct=svmtrain(train_x,train_y,'kernel_function','rbf','rbf_sigma',rbfsigma,'boxconstraint',0.7,'showplot','false');
fun = @(train_x, train_y,test_x ,test_y) sum(svmclassify(svmStruct,X(P.test,:)) ~= Y(P.test)); 

opts = statset('display','iter'); 
[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,X,Y,'cv',P,'options',opts);
```

Comment: Could you precise your question? There is no such thing as "best features". It depends on your data set, on the output that you want, on the constraints you have...

Comment: this code work good but i want use svmclassify. >> f = @(xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest) sum(ytest ~= classify(xtest, xtrain, ytrain));
>>  fs = sequentialfs(f,x,y)